# How to use the Google App Engine as a backend database for Android applications

Tags: android, database, google-app-engine, database-connection, backend

I'm actually a beginner in android and needs a lot of help. I have made an app with embedded database and now want to put it onto some dynamic location. Have simple form of data (some addresses and branch information etc). I actually have no idea about how to use a dynamic server placed on dynamic location.

How can I do this? Please guide me stepwise

I browsed and found some terms like "**write Service**", "**Close/open back-ends**" etc. Kindly do guide me. Another question that I have is: do I need some kind of registration, api-key or any other thing. I just added the "google plugins" for eclipse and I can create **App engine connected with Android App**

Comment: Why does android need a lot of help ? Have you even tried writing some code ?

Comment: yeah dear friend; I made this complete app with embedded database but no any idea about using the server database. So needs here guidance...

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/

Comment: Thats the issue, with SO its a Question Answer forum only. No one has the time to give elaborate software development consultation or advice.You will receive a lot of down votes and also flags for closing your questions.

Comment: you are true about 90% people, thanks

Comment: I want to use this same method.What "embeded database" did you use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you do need a key.  Look at this http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

**First, we need to send data to/from the client** for the example you set up ([App engine connected with Android App](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae)) using

```
com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender helper class
```

Again, that helper class is step #4 and how to use it is in [Writing the Server-side Application Server-side Application](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#server-app)

**Naturally then you want to persist or look up data.**  You can do that in the whatever class is used to send/receive messages (which of course uses the Sender helper class above)

*Then the easiest and maybe best way for AppEngine if you are using Java is to use Objectify.*  Trust me or google it to see how good it is.  https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/

The docs for Objectify are really good and I didn't really have any trouble the first times.

Their simple example is:

```
@Entity
class Car {
    @Id String vin; // Can be Long, long, or String
    String color;
}

ofy().save().entity(new Car("123123", "red")).now();
Car c = ofy().load().type(Car.class).id("123123").get();
ofy().delete().entity(c);
```

I think you are good to go.

Summary:

- YourMessageClass (on Appengine)

  -- uses com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender to send/recieve data

  -- uses Objectify to persist data.

The next question is where are you putting YourMessageClass.  Will it be in a Servlet that is handling a short-lived request? (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Requests_and_Servlets)  Will it be in a long-running backend?  (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/) but that is beyond the scope of this discussion.