# Android : GCM application Server maintaining registration ids

Tags: android, google-app-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement GCM push notifications for my Android application. I have implemented GCM Client in my Android app by referring [this link](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/). In GCM client it has a method:

```
/**
 * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send
 * messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the device sends upstream messages
 * to a server that echoes back the message using the 'from' address in the message.
 */
 private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() 
 {
     // Your implementation here.
 }
```

I was trying to find out the ways in which the registration ids can be stored at the backend. While searching I got to know that Google App Engine can be used to deploy the server side code by referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008958/how-to-use-the-google-app-engine-as-a-backend-database-for-android-applications) 
As per my knowledge for every android application to implement push notifications to client, they would require list of all the registration ids. Following are few of my questions

- Is there not any simple mechanism to get all registration ids?
- Doesn't GCM server stores all the ids?
- Does all GCM Server application are required to implement the way in which the registration ids are stored?
- If while sending the updates to client, I want to send the updates to all the registered devices irrespective of any criteria, isn't there any method by which I can do it? I think all the applications would be requiring this kind of service. Isn't there a common way by which this can be achieved? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The only way to get all the registration IDs of the devices that installed your app is to maintain a DB of those devices in your server. Or you can use a 3rd party provider (such as UrbanAirship) to do it for you.
- The GCM server has all those IDs, but there's no API call that returns all registered registration IDs for a given app.
- Each application that uses GCM requires a server side that would maintain a list of registered devices, and send messages to the devices. You can use a 3rd party push provider to do that for you.
- If you want to send the updates to all registered devices, you have to specify all the registration IDs for which you want to send the message. If all devices get the same message, you can send the message to a 1000 registration IDs in one HTTP request (and if you have more than a 1000 devices, you'll have to do multiple requests).

Comment: Thanks Eran for info.

Comment: I am using google app engine to host my web application, So can use the same as third party push provider.

Comment: @Eran Can you please tell me how to do multiple requests?

Comment: @Programmer If you know how to make a single request - make a single request and repeat as many times as required

Comment: @Eran Thanks. But I am using App Engine and it has MessageEndpoint.java class there which sends message. If I am not  wrong this is what you call request right? I am sorry I am new to android gcm.Please help!

Comment: @Programmer I'm not familiar with MessageEndpoint, so I can't say. What I call a request is a single HTTP request sent to GCM server.